# Center TopLevel window, keeping dynamic sizing of grid/pack geometry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to center a `TopLevel` window, to the middle of it's parent window (`Tk` or `TopLevel` window). The problem is I want to keep the dynamic sizing of the window that `.pack()` and `.grid()`, geometry managers of tkinter, give (the window size scales depending on how much size is needed).

I want to do this without having to use the `update()`, which I know would solve my problem, because I don't want the window to flash up and then quickly flash to the location it is meant to be.

> This is my best attempt so far, the problem is that it removes the
>   dynamic sizing.

```py
from tkinter import *


def center_to_win(window, master):
    x = master.winfo_x()
    y = master.winfo_y()
    w = window.winfo_reqwidth()
    h = window.winfo_reqheight()
    total_x = x + (master.winfo_width() // 2) - (w // 2)
    total_y = y + (master.winfo_height() // 2) - (h // 2)
    window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (int(w), int(h), int(total_x), int(total_y)))


class MainWin(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.update()
        pu = PopUp(self)


class PopUp(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(PopUp, self).__init__(master)
        for i in range(20):
            label = Label(self, text="label i")
            label.grid(column=0, row=i)
        center_to_win(self, master)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWin()
    win.mainloop()
```

If anyone knows how to do this, without having the window flash on screen, that would be a great help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is kinda not possible for a window to update without `update()` before `mainloop()` executes. However it can be done without  flashing the window by updating the window when it's hidden. *We can use `window.wm_withdraw()` to hide and `window.wm_deiconify()` to show*, the delay is not noticeable at least on my system. [`window.iconify()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method) can also be used in place of [`window.wm_withdraw()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method) but **it cannot be used together with [`transient()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method).**

Chances to make function `center_to_win()` to centralise one window on another.

```
def center_to_win(window, master):
    window.wm_withdraw()
    window.update()
    x = master.winfo_x()
    y = master.winfo_y()
    w = window.winfo_reqwidth()
    h = window.winfo_reqheight()
    total_x = x + (master.winfo_width() // 2) - (w // 2)
    total_y = y + (master.winfo_height() // 2) - (h // 2)
    window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (int(w), int(h), int(total_x), int(total_y)))
    window.wm_deiconify()
```

Calling the function just by `center_to_win(self, master)` works completely fine but I noticed an issue when you set geometery of main window in the starting it can be fixed by calling the function like this `self.after(1, center_to_win, self, master)`. Though it was very random and it might not happen to you but in case if it does then use `after(..)`.

---

***For dynamic sizing.***

Though this fixes the dynamic sizing issue but you should use `self.grid_rowconfigure(index, weight=1)` and `self.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=1)` for *grid* layout.

```
...

for i in range(20):
    self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    label = Label(self, text="label i")
    label.grid(column=0, row=i)
...
```

Comment: This worked just great, I was hoping there was a way to set the x and y of a window without setting its width and height, but I couldn't find it anywhere so I wasn't expecting there to be. I can't notice the delay with this though, so thanks!